# I could not dispaly noroom component if there is no place name that user has queried

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I have a search form where user search for place. If the place that user has typed is in the api (response object) then i want to display Room component else NoRoom component. When i type the place that is not in the api , my NoRoom component is not displayed.

```
search( query='place' ){
    let url = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/rental/?place__startswith="+encodeURIComponent(query);
    Request.get(url).then((response) => {
        console.log('response',response.body.objects);
        this.setState({
            place:response.body.objects,
        });
    });
  }

  searchUpdated(term){
    this.search(term);
  }

  render() {
        var margin = { marginTop : '13em' };
        if (this.state.place){
        let location = _.map(this.state.place, (place,id) => {
            return(
                    <Room key={id}
                    slug={place.slug}
                    place={place.place}
                    city={place.city}
                    gallery={place.gallery}
                    property={place.property}/>
                )
            console.log('location',location);
        });
        let gallery = _.map(this.state.place, (place,id) => {
            console.log('place',place.gallery);
            _.map(place.gallery, (image,id) => {
                return(
                        <img src={image.image} class="img-fluid" />
                    )
            });
        });
        return(
            <div className = "container">
                <div className="content text-align-center">
                    <div className="row text-xs-center">
                        <div className="middle-text"  style={margin}>
                            <h1 className="welcome"><span>Rental Space Welcome's you </span></h1>
                            <button ref="test" className="btn how-it-works" onClick={this.handleClick}>Search Space</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="mySearch" className="overlay"  onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}>
                  <button className="btn closebtn" onClick={this.handleClick}>x</button>
                  <div className="overlay-content">
                        <SearchInput ref="searchInput" className="search-input" onChange={this.searchUpdated} />
                         <div className="container searchList">
                                { location }
                        </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            );
    }
    else{
        return(
            <NoRoom />
            )
    }
    }
}

class Room extends React.Component{
    render(){
        let imageFile = this.props.gallery.map((image) => {
            return(
                    <img src={image.image} className="img-fluid" width="250px" height="250px" />
                );
        });
        return(
                <div className="room">
                     <div className="thumbnail">
                        { imageFile[0] }
                    </div>
                    <h3 className="listingName text-left">
                     <a href = { "/rent/" + this.props.slug }>{this.props.place}</a>
                    </h3>
                    <span className="propertySpan">
                        <i className = "fa fa-home"></i>
                        <span className="property">{this.props.property}</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            )
    }
}

class NoRoom extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>No Room</div>
            )
    }
}
```

You can see in image, No Room text is not displayed when there is no place called kat
[image]

What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you root-component, your local state (this.state.place) is an array that defines whether you display the Room component or the NoRoom component.

If your API doesn't find any matching place, then this.state.place is an empty array, which is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). That's why you just have to check the length of the array in your render method:

```
if (this.state.place.length > 0) {
```

*Detailed explanation:*

Your UI behavior is defined by the component state. The initial structure of this state must be described in your component, this is what you do in the component constructor:

```
this.state = {place: []};
```

This initial state will be used during the 1st rendering of the component.

Then, each time you want to update this state, you call this.setState() with a new value for the property "place", which must be an array for consistency.

In your render() method, you just have to describe your UI according to the current value of your state. Because "place" is always an array, the only thing you can do to check if you have data in it is to test the "length" property of this array (length === 0 when no data). If you only check the array itself like you did initially (if (this.state.place) { ... }), it will always evaluate to "true" (because an array, even empty, is always "truthy") and it's not what you want.

Comment: i have attached an image in my question.

Comment: what is the format of the "response" object when your API doesn't find any matching place?

Comment: I have attached an image which shows the log files n console too. Response objects is shown [] empty array.

Comment: Allright, then it's just a problem in your state checking (I updated my answer).

Comment: well i get this error app.js:19820 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined response [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] app.js:7544 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null

Comment: How do you initialize your local state in your root-component? It should be something like: this.state = {place: []}; in your constructor.

Comment: yes its working like a charm. Thanks a lot. Could you please explain me in brief how your idea worked ?

Comment: Yes, I just updated my answer with a detailed explanation.